# Peticion del lado del servidor con next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next

estoy intentando hacer la peticion desde el servidor con next, para mantener

informacion sensible oculta, pero siempre recibo undefined, siendo que son

api que siempre utilizo, quisiera saber en que me estoy equivocando o estoy

haciendo mal, les dejo el codigo donde hago la petición, gracias de antemano

```
   import fetch from 'isomorphic-fetch'

   function Instagram({ json }) {
   console.log(json)
       return (
          <div>
            h2>Peticion desde backend</h2>
          </div>
        );
      }

    Instagram.getServerSideProps = async () => {
        let res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/')
        let json = await res.json()
        console.log(json)
      return { props: json };
      };

     export default Instagram;
```

Comment: aclaro que ya probe tambien con staticprop, e initialprop dando el mismo resultado

Answer (score 0):

Por si a alguien le sirve, estaba haciendo la peticion desde un componente, poreso es que me daba undefined la respuesta, una vez que lo hice como una page, next me lo tomo correctamente, espero les sirva